# Printing Values In Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[Sample Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfzWp.png)

Please Refer the above Screenshot attached here.As i have find max Value of two numbers ,I also want to print Value whose number is max ie Hello,how do i achieve this?

Comment: Step 1: Think. Step 2: Try. Step 3: Research. Step 4: Try again. If still failing, step 5: Post your question, research and attempts here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the following formula

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MAX(B:B),B:B,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to also print `Hello` or `World`? Am I right? Try this:

```
=index(a1:a3, match(d2, b1:b3, 0))
```

Comment: in this case i want to print value "Hello" Because 4 is greater than 1.The above formula doesn't works :(

Comment: It is the same as the answer you've accepted since d2 is `max(b1, b3)` in your screenshot. If this doesn't work, your screenshot is wrong. Obviously you didn't try anything yourself, even think anything.